# Changing JavaScript's global object?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to change the *root* object in JavaScript?

For example, in browsers, the *root* object is "window". So

```
X = 5;
console.log(Y);
```

is the same as:

```
window.X = 5;
console.log(window.Y);
```

What I want to do now, is changing this *root* object, so when I do the following:

```
X = 6;
```

**Reason why I need this:**

In [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) applications, every part of the program can access the global object. That's a big problem because every script that is executed by a Node.js webserver can add new variables to it. They will be there until the webserver is restarted. I want to avoid this by changing the global object.

**Update**

I've tested the following code and got a really interesting result.
What did you expect of the following code?

```
var X = {A:"a",B:"b"};

with(X){
    A = 5;
    C = 7;
}
for(a in X){
    console.log(a+" is "+X[a]);
}

/* 
Expected Console Output:
A is 5
B is b
C is 7

Real Console Output:
A is 5;
B is b;

*/
```

Is there a way to get output as I expected it?

**Update**

I've now tested the module system with the following code.

```
//program.js
var t = require("./module.js");
t.Test();

console.log(A);

//module.js
A = 5;
exports.Test = function(){
    console.log("hello world!");
}
```

The output was:

```
hello world!
5
```

This tells me, that the variable "A" defined in `module.js` was added to the global object of `program.js`. The module does not solve my problem, either.

Comment: Proper term is not *ROOT* but `Global`, in browsers `window` implements `Global`

Comment: If you use "use strict"; on top of your code, your example is not possible. I came here because I want to do the same, actually I want to replace the global object with a proxy object. This is working fine however lost it's global scope. I think it has something to do with a reference to the old object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement, but it is not recommended and forbidden in strict mode.

It is better to refer to the variable holding the object explicitly.

In response to updated question:

`with` will search up the scope chain until it finds an object with a matching property or gets to `window`. It is no good for defining new properties on an object.

```
var X = { A: 5, B: 8, C: 7};
with(X){
    console.log(A, B, C);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot "with", it's exactly what i search for. It does not matter if it is forbidden or not. It must only run in the V8 engine, and it seems to work.

Comment: Ok i was to fast... it does not work as I expected it. I updated my post.

Comment: @Flash: I'm certain I'm not as familiar with the `with` statement as @David, but it seems that `with` looks for a property in `X`, and if not found, it traverses the scope chain. If none are found, it creates global variables. It seems to use `with`, you'd need to first define those properties. `var X = {A:null,B:null,C:null,D:"D"};`

Comment: Yes I found out the same thing. But thats a problem... I don't want do predefine the values. That would be senseless in my case.

Comment: @Flash: I just updated my answer with another possibility. There are a number of ways to approach this. The simplest is to simply reference the object when adding properties *(as David recommended in his answer)*.

Comment: the main question is: Is there a way to change the root object in JavaScript/Node.js? Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: in Node, there's the VM package, https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html
"A common use case is to run the code in a different V8 Context. This means invoked code has a different global object than the invoking code."
but it also says: 
"The vm module is not a security mechanism. Do not use it to run untrusted code."

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about variables, JavasScript has function scope.

```
X = 5;  // global variable

console.log( window.X );  // 5

(function() {
   var X = 6;  // declare a local variable by using the "var" keyword

   console.log( X );  // 6
})();

console.log( window.X );  // 5
```

Otherwise, you can create an Object, and add properties to it.

```
X = 5; 

console.log( window.X );  // 5

var obj = {};

obj.X = 6;

console.log( obj.X ); // 6

console.log( window.X );  // 5
```

---

**EDIT:** Adding another *possible* solution that *could* be used.

You could invoke an anonymous function, but set the context of the function to your `X` object. Then `this` in the function will refer to `X`.

```
var X = {};
(function(){
    this.A = 5;
    this.B = 8;
    this.C = 7;
}).call(X);
for(a in X){
    console.log(a+" is "+X[a]);
}
```

The `.call()` method (as well as the `.apply()` method) allow you to explicitly set the *thisArg*`of a calling context. The first argument you pass will be how`this` is defined in the context of the invocation.

Or just pass `X` in as an argument.

```
var X = {};
(function(X){
    X.A = 5;
    X.B = 8;
    X.C = 7;
})(X);
for(a in X){
    console.log(a+" is "+X[a]);
}
```

Though the simplest is to simply reference it (as I noted in my answer above).

```
var X = {};
X.A = 5;
X.B = 8;
X.C = 7;
for(a in X){
    console.log(a+" is "+X[a]);
}
```

---

or use a *module* pattern:

```
   /****** I'm guessing at the use of "global" here ********/
global.myNamespace = (function(global,undefined) {

    // define the object to be returned
    var X = {};

    //  define private local variables
    var a_local = 'some value';
    var another_local = 'some other value';

    // define private functions
    function myFunc() {
        // do something with local variables
    }

    // give the return object public members
    X.someProperty = 'some value';
    X.anotherProperty = 'another value';
    X.publicFunc = function() {
        //do something with the local variables
        //    or public properties
    };
    X.anotherFunc = function() {
        //do something with the local variables
        //    or public properties
    };
    // return the object
    return X;

})(global);

console.log(myNamespace);
```

Comment: @Down-voter: Please explain. Which part of my answer is incorrect?

Comment: @David: Thanks for the response. Could you please explain which bit that is? I don't think OP is familiar with javascript, and as such when OP does `X = 5`, and sees it adding a property to `window`, I'm guessing an assumption is being made that that's how properties are generally added. Depending on the specific need, either of these solutions could be helpful IMO.

Comment: + 1 for a really good answer. But David's answer gets closest to my expected solution.

Comment: BTW To explain why I wanted to do it like i posted it: In Node.js applications every part of the program can access the Global object. That's a big problem because every script that is executed by a Node.js Webserver can add new Variables to it. They will be there until the Webserver is restarted. I wanted to avoid this by changing the global object.

Comment: @FlashFan: I see what you're getting at, but `with` can (as you now know) give unexpected results if you're not careful. I may be wrong, but it sounds like you're looking for a new variable scope for your code. The only way to accomplish that in javascript is in a function. There's no block scope (except with the non-standard `let` keyword, which I don't believe `V8` implements). I'd get rid of `with` (if you haven't yet) and use a single global namespace that is unique enough that it won't be overwritten, then do your code manipulation in an immediately invoked function expression.

Comment: @patrick dw: I can calm you: I don't use while in my code, because it does not help me in my situation. I know the module pattern, I'll read more about it to understand if it prevents my problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @FlashFan: No need to *"calm"* me. ;o) I'm just letting you know that there are options out there. I understood your comment above to mean that you needed a private variable scope. So you're not using `with`. That wasn't clear.

Comment: ^^ It was just a joke ;) I've tested the module system. It also allows the script to access and store variables on the global object. It's frustrating, because node.js is a really good thing. Except of this... I'll add the testing code above.

Comment: @Flash: Are you declaring your variables inside the module with the `var` keyword? I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @patrick dw: No, I didn't. But this does not matter. What I wanted to find out was if there exists access to the real global object. And so it is.

Comment: @Flash: Yes indeed. If you exclude `var` you're creating implicit globals unless a matching identifier was already declared in the scope chain.

Comment: @patrick: Hmmm... that's a real problem for me. Maybe the only possibility is to use nginx as webserver and then let it pass the request to one of multiple node.js servers. So I can guarantee that they don't interfere with each other.

Comment: @FlashFan: I'll admit that I don't have experience with node.js. Is there some reason you wouldn't just declare private variables in a function like I did above? Or create a single namespace and declare properties on it? What is the particular situation?

Comment: ...I didn't previously notice that you update the question. Again, I'm not too familiar with node.js, so I'm not sure what `module.js` is supposed to do. The module pattern I'm referring to is the last patter that I added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way in EcmaScript 6 to adjust `with(context) { ... }`, so that any new variables we assign will go into the `context` object, not the global / `window` object.

Thanks to this article [Metaprogramming in ES6: Part 3 - Proxies](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-part-3-proxies/) for teaching me about the ES6 Proxy feature.

In the proxy:

- We override `has` to return `true`, so our context appears to have all properties, and when we set any variable it will go to the object.
- We override `get` to get the property from our context, or if it isn't really there, we get the property from an `up` object (which defaults to the global `window`).

I know that `with` is frowned upon, but this technique enables to create mutable extensible modules where we can access members conveniently as `foo` rather than `Module.foo`, and I don't think it is unsafe or ambiguous.

```js
function scope(x, up=window) {
    return new Proxy(x, {
        has: (o, k) => true,
        get: (o, k) => k in o ? o[k] : up[k]
    });
}

var Test = {};

with (scope(Test)) {
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
    add_x = function(y) {
        console.log(x + y);
    }
}

Test.add_x(10);

with (scope(Test)) {
    x = 3;
    add_y = function(x) {
        console.log(x + y);
    }
}

Test.add_x(20);

Test.y = 5;

Test.add_y(30);
```

Comment: The only problem I found so far is calling `setTimeout`, a method on `window`, from inside the module. It calls it with the wrong `this`. The easiest workaround is just to invoke it as `window.setTimeout`, or we can modify the `scope` proxy to pass through a certain set of methods. I tried a few other workarounds which didn't work.