# Changing the behavior of JavaScript's with statement to prevent assignment from modifying the global object

Tags: javascript, while-loop

The `with` statement in JavaScript first checks if the requested property of the object exists before it decides if it should set the property of the given object or the property of the global object.

Example:

```
var x = {a:5};

with(x){
    a = 6; //x.a is now 6
    b = 7; //window.b is now 7, x.b still does not exist
}
```

I want to change the behavior of `with`, so that when it checks for the presence of a property on the object I'm working with it will always treat it as though it exists, preventing assignments within the block from accidentally modifying the global object.

Could this be accomplished by overloading the function that checks whether the property of the object exists or not? For example something like this:

```
Object.prototype.__hasOwnProperty__ = function(p){
    return true;
}

var x = {a:5};

with(x){
    a = 6; //x.a is now 6
    b = 7; //x.b should now be 7
}
```

My code runs on node.js & V8, so it doesn't matter if the solutions only work with this.

Hope someone has an ide how I realize this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The question is: Which function must be overloaded to make the code within the with statement defining b ond object x instead of defining it on the window/global object?

Comment: Why won't you describe exactly what you want to accomplish? The `with` statement doesn't do what you want. You already knew this from your previous question. Is there some reason you won't look at any solution that is more appropriate for the language you're using?

Comment: What I want to do: I want to totally isolate the global object from code which is executed within the with statement. The code should simply not be able to access the global object. This is an important thing for me. Imagine you develop a server which runs 24/7 without restart. This server executes very much different scripts using the eval() command. What's when a script defines a variable on the global object? It will be there until the server restarts. This is a momory leak ;)

Comment: Imagine your apache server would keep every global variable your php ever defined in memory, and would only kill them on a restart ;) Your memory would of course not be happy ;)

Comment: @FlashFan: Is there a reason your scripts you're running are using `eval()`?  I hate to say it, but that's the other feature of javascript that is generally recommended you avoid. It seems that you're trying to use what are commonly considered *the bad parts* of javascript.

Comment: ^^ can you say me how I can include and run scripts in other files without eval? Yes, there is that module thing, but I think this uses also eval ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to fundamentally change how the `with` statement works in JavaScript. This isn't possible, because you have no guarantee that the interpreter is using `hasOwnProperty` (or any other construct you have access to) to check for the presence of a property on the object you're working with.

You're joining a nice tradition of wishing that `with` worked differently, but it doesn't. It works how it does and it's best avoided.

Comment: Do you have an other idea how I could reach a behaviour described in the comments of my post?

Comment: @FlashPan - It's just not possible. This is just part of how JS works. There is an implicit global object. You have to live with it. Following best practices protects you from a lot of problems. Always use `var` to declare variables and avoid the `with` statement.

Comment: ^^ OK. Node.js could be really good, but because of this fact, I doubt that it really can be used for huge & high-performance projects :S

Comment: I now programmed a trick that does what I want. I added it as answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Don't modify the `Object.prototype`. It's considered bad practice and will cause unexpected result everywhere, plus other JS frameworks won't even run if it's been modified.
2. Please don't use `with`. It is being deprecated from javascript because it can't be determined how it should best function when there is local variable with the same name as a property.

If you need to iterate over the properties of an object, just do this:

```
for (var i in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        // processing logic here
    }
}
```

You mentioned code that would help you achieve overriding that setting logic. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects has information on using **defineSetter** to override the setting portion, but it is highly recommended, on not even possible from JavaScript 1.8.1 and after. I would recommend another approach.

Comment: ^^ but this would be the only way to do what I wanted in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052599/javascript-changing-the-global-object

Comment: Tell me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Eli I'm pretty sure he's trying to change the behavior of `with` so that when it checks whether `x` above already has property `b`, it will treat it as though it does, so that `x.b` is assigned `7` instead of the global object.

Comment: @Eli In other words, he's trying to make `with` behave so that it doesn't have the problem you mention in #2.

Comment: No way to change the functionality of `with`. Like I said, a helper method that will achieve the same thing is recommended.

Comment: Since everyone seems to be misunderstanding the question, I'm going to try to edit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

To keep variables out of the global scope, you can use an anonymous function; since JavaScript has functional scoping, all variables defined in a function are local in scope. It requires you to declare variables properly, though, but I would highly suggest that under any circumstance.

```
(function () {
    var a = 1;
    alert("a is... " + a);
    // do more stuff here
}());
alert(typeof a); // should be undefined
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AWDzV/

This doesn't specifically deal with your `with` statement, but it is probably the best way to accomplish what you're looking for. Then, all you have to do to emulate the behavior of the `with` statement is to use a variable:

```
(function () {
    var a = 1,
        some_very_long_object_name = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
        obj = some_very_long_object_name;
    obj.a = 2;
    obj.b = 3;
    obj.c = 4;
}());
alert(typeof a); // should be undefined
```

Not the best code in the world, but it does demonstrate that using a short variable name to replace a long object name works perfectly. All-in-all, I feel this is probably the best solution.

Of course, any variable not declared properly will "leak" into the global scope:

```
(function () {
    a = 1; // notice the lack of "var" keyword
}());
alert(a); // should be 1
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AWDzV/1/

But you can use [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) to help catch that particular error. Running it on the above code yields the following error message:

> Error: Implied global: a 2,4, alert 4

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to totally isolate a skript. It's not good code, but it works.

```
X = 5;
function ExecuteIsolated(code){
    var vars = [];
    (function(){
        for(var v in window){
            vars.push(v);                   
        }           
        eval("var "+vars.join(",")+";");

        //Totally isolated code here:           
        eval(code);     
        //End of totally isolated code
    })();
    var i = 0;
    for(var v in window){
        if(vars[i++] != v){
            delete window[v];
            i--;
        }
    }
}       
ExecuteIsolated("X = 8");
console.log(X);
```

Maybe its useful for someone else ;)

Comment: Are you aware that `for-in` provides no guaranteed order of enumeration? What code is being eval'd? Is it code from a known and trusted source?

Comment: Yes it are trusted sources, but sources where I can't guarantee that the code doesn't store much data in the global object.