# Isolated execution context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm trying to execute a piece of code within an empty isolated execution context in JavaScript. In the below sample, I'm trying isolate `isolated` execution scope. What I want to do is to execute a function in context where no global variables are in.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var scope = Object.create(null);
  var isolated = function() {
    'use strict';
    console.log(document); // Trying to get undefined
                           // but traces `document`.
  };

  isolated.call(scope);
})();
```

I thought it was simple to *nullify* global variables but there are too many!

```
var isolated = function(window, document, location /* etc */) {
  // ...
};

isolated.call(scope, undefined, undefined, undefined /* etc */);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How about using web workers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: I found a way in EcmaScript 6 to adjust `with(context) { ... }`, so that any new variables we assign will go into the context object, not the global / window object. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62350258/218294

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *good* way to do this within javascript itself (but see Gareth Hayes answer for another option).

There are a couple of bad ways.

```
(function() {
  var scope = Object.create(null);
  var obscurer = {};
  for (var key in this) {
     obscurer[key] = undefined;
  }

  with (obscurer) {
    var isolated = function() {
      'use strict';
      console.log(document);
    };
  }

  isolated.call(scope);
})();
```

Note that you'll actually get an error because console is not defined rather than document, although you can fix this by not blocking 'console' in the obscurer object.  You'll probably find that you need a whole bunch more globals than you realised.

You're also only blocking the *enumerable* properties of window.  If you become aware of nonenumerable properties that you want to block too, you'll have to add those to obscurer.

Of course, using `with` means you can't use strict mode any more as well, and everyone will look down their noses at you..

There are more interesting options available if you are working within node rather than the browser.

Comment: Window.prototype.alert.call(window,1) bypasses this sandbox.

Comment: I get "TypeError: window is undefined", but yes, I wouldn't really consider this method to be *safe*.  As far as I know, you can't make a safe sandbox without parsing the input code.  And even then, there are plenty of mistakes that could be made (e.g. people often forget that the Function constructor lets them eval code).

Comment: It's a Firefox specific vector.

Comment: I ran it in the console on firefox nightly, so I don't know if it's the version of firefox or the console that made it work for me.  I suppose it highlights the point that if you're really looking for safety there are a lot of edge cases to think about.  It'd be interesting to know exactly why Florent wants to do this...

Comment: It works on Chrome as well actually 32.0.1700.72 m. But yeah this is my point you miss one thing and it's a full bypass whereas if you use a parser and whitelist it's much stronger against attack.

Comment: Just to emphasise that this code isn't safe - I noticed that in non-strict mode you can delete top level values, if you are in a non strict function, you could, for example `delete window;` and that would delete the window in obscurer, which would let you access the global.... In es5, you could make the undefined non-deletable, but at some point it's like pushing down bubbles in a screen protector film.

Comment: what options might we have in Node.js rather than browser?

Comment: I created this gist, and I can't get this to work with a local variable instead of a global variable, any help appreciated: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/6f616ea88d34dba83e1cfdc43b7aff67

Answer (score 2):

Use my MentalJS parser to isolate the environment. You can then choose which objects/variables it has access to by customizing the code.

http://businessinfo.co.uk/labs/MentalJS/MentalJS.html

http://code.google.com/p/mentaljs/

By default it allows access to document but you can prevent this, customize the environment here http://code.google.com/p/mentaljs/source/browse/trunk/MentalJS/javascript/Mental.js#260 you can then choose if they have access to Math etc.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without ECMA6 by using an IIFE that contains your trusted-needs-protection code, into which you inject your untrusted-needs-isolation-code (see example).

```
(function(injectedFunction) {
    /* Trusted code, that needs protection from untrusted code access */
    var hostingFuncPrivatePrimitive = "Hello there";
    var hostingFuncPrivateObject = {
        this_is_mine: true
    };

    var sharedPrimitive = 'This is shared';
    var sharedObject = {};

    // Running the untrusted code:
    injectedFunction(sharedPrimitive, sharedObject);

    console.log("sharedObject is: " + JSON.stringify(sharedObject));
    console.log("hostingFuncPrivateObject is: " +
        JSON.stringify(hostingFuncPrivateObject));
})(

(function(primitiveArg, objArg) {
    /* Untrusted code that needs isolation */

    // 1. using primitive (legal)
    console.log('primitiveArg is: ' + primitiveArg);

    // 2. Writing value to given objArg (legal):
    objArg.mumu = 'mimi';

    // 3. Trying to access host function variables (illegal)
    try {
        console.log('hostingFuncPrivatePrimitive is:' +
            hostingFuncPrivatePrimitive);
        hostingFuncPrivateObject.this_is_mine = false;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})

);
```

If you place the above in Chrome's console, you will get:

```
    primitiveArg is: This is shared
    VM117:29 ReferenceError: hostingFuncPrivatePrimitive is not defined
            at <anonymous>:26:17
            at <anonymous>:11:5
            at <anonymous>:16:3
    VM117:12 sharedObject is: {"mumu":"mimi"}
    VM117:13 hostingFuncPrivateObject is: {"this_is_mine":true}
```

P.S.: I know I'm late to the party, but maybe this helps anybody.